# NSTokenField does not show suggestion Popup

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I use an NSTokenField, but it does not show the puppy with the suggestions after the specified delay

I tried like this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController 
{ @IBOutlet weak var tokenFiled: NSTokenField!

  override func viewDidLoad()
  { super.viewDidLoad()

    tokenFiled.delegate = self
    tokenFiled.tokenStyle = .default
    tokenFiled.completionDelay = 0.25  
  }

  override var representedObject: Any? 
  { didSet { } }
}

extension ViewController:  NSTokenFieldDelegate, NSTokenFieldCellDelegate
{
  func tokenFieldCell(_ tokenFieldCell: NSTokenFieldCell, completionsForSubstring substring: String, indexOfToken tokenIndex: Int, indexOfSelectedItem selectedIndex: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> [Any]
  {
    let names = ["Name1", "Name 2", "Name3"]
    return names
  }
}
```

Any Ideas, what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

I used the wrong delegate method.

```
func tokenFieldCell(_ tokenFieldCell: NSTokenFieldCell, completionsForSubstring substring: String, indexOfToken tokenIndex: Int, indexOfSelectedItem selectedIndex: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> [Any]
```

instead of:

```
func tokenField(_ tokenField: NSTokenField, completionsForSubstring substring: String, indexOfToken tokenIndex: Int, indexOfSelectedItem selectedIndex: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>?) -> [Any]?
```

which works fine now